# Can't open file 'winsock2.lib' C++

Tags: c++, linker, visual-studio-2019, linker-errors

I've tried adding the library winsock2.lib to the additional dependencies in the `Project properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`. But it still can't open it and gives me this error message

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'winsock2.lib' Login and registration system   D:\Programming projects\C++\Login and registration system\Login and registration system\LINK    1
```

Comment: The library is called `WS2_32.Lib`.

Comment: Where do you expect your linker to find this file? Is this path added to the additional link directories?

Comment: @Axalo same error

Comment: @RoQuOTriX It is not linked to a directory because I didn't download a file called winsock2 so I don't know what path to put in the directory

Comment: `ws2_32.lib` (not `winsock2.lib`) is part of the Windows SDK, which should already be installed if you are using C++ in Visual Studio. The `.lib` should already exist in the IDE's default lib directories, so you can just refer to it by filename without a path.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket

You should add the `Ws2_32.lib` instead of `winsock2.lib`.

To add the lib, I suggest you could try to the following code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
```

You could also try to add the name of the .lib file with its extension to Additional Dependencies: `property -> linker -> input -> Additional Dependencies`

Comment: @Khaled Taha Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.